# Drivers for Dell Precision M90 and Windows Server 2008 (R1)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-server-2008

I am trying to get multi monitor support for my laptop.  I have installed Windows Server 2008 (R1) x64 and none of the dell drivers for my laptop seem to work (I have tried the x64 ones for Vista and XP, they don't offer Win7 ones yet).

Drivers downloaded from NVidia do not work (NVidia says I need to get my Drivers from Dell).

Do I have any alternatives?

I need to get two monitors to work so I can do a presentation from my laptop this Saturday.

My Video card is an NVidia Quadro FX 4800m (I tried the NVidia Quadro FX 4800 driver and it would not install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up going with was at http://laptopvideo2go.com/

The help make an INF file that allows more relaxed rules for installing a NVidia Driver.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully a silly question, but are you using the Quadro FX Notebook drivers. It is a seperate download and they do have Win7, and Server 2003 X64 listed (I just checked). If anything, you might need to setup to dual-boot into a supported OS.